# Is there a built-in way to have unfilled stroked SVG objects clickable?

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am writing an SVG editor, and up until now all of the objects it created had fills. But after implementing other features, I'm rather surprised to find out that unfilled SVG elements don't respond to the click event event even when they have a stroke.

Is there another event or a CSS setting that will make them clickable? Or do I have to get points along the path and find them on my own?

I'm using D3.js for a lot of the code BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [pointer-events property](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty) I suspect

```
pointer-events: visible;
```

is what you're looking for.

Comment: Do I add this to the stylesheet for the app?

Comment: You can if you want, it's a CSS property, use it like any other CSS property

Comment: It looks like pointer-events: painted works in the stylesheet, but it is less than ideal because the click has to be very precisely on the edge of the element. I may have to duplicate all of the elements in the drawing that aren't filled with a nearly completely transparent identical object on top of it with a stroke width that is perhaps about 3 pixels wide. I don't want to have something clickable in its interior if it is not filled.

Comment: Use pointer- events: fill with fill: none. Then non filled elements are clickable...

Comment: This answer should be useful to someone else. In my case I want

    pointer-events:painted

... because I really loathe having unfilled items clickable in their interior especially when you are zoomed in. CorelDraw added this dumb feature as the default setting which makes the program almost thoroughly hostile in selecting the correct elements. 

Clicking on nothing should unselect the current selection, not click another object.